# very slow query in web application, but super fast in linqpad

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq, firebird

i am using Entity framework with **Firebird** database wich look like this
[image]

and here the query i am running

```
Int32 nn = 4308;
VISITE v = VISITEs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.VINUM == nn);
DateTime d = (DateTime) v.DATEVIS;
Int32 p = (Int32) v.PANUM;

// First Select   
var numberGroups = from n in VISRUBs.Where(a => a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS <= d && a.VISANA.VISITE.PANUM == p)
 group n by n.RUBRIQUE into g

select new {
    RemainderCHAPLIB = g.Key.ANALYSE.CHAPITRE.LIBELLE,
    RemainderLIB = g.Key.LIBELLE,
    RemainderRUNUM = g.Key.RUNUM,
    vals = from vlist in g.OrderByDescending(a => a.VISANA.VISITE.DATEVIS)
    select vlist.VALEUR
};

//Second Select 
var lst = from n in numberGroups.
ToList().Where(a => a.RemainderLIB != null)
 select new {
    RemainderCHAPLIB = n.RemainderCHAPLIB,
    RemainderLIB = n.RemainderLIB,
    RemainderRUNUM = n.RemainderRUNUM,
    VAL = n.vals.FirstOrDefault(),
    ANT = n.vals.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
};
```

it take bout 0.08s in linqpad , but about 60 seconds in web application !!!

it hangs at the ToList() statement

at this point i really don't know what to think , so any help or idea is more than welcome .

thanks and good day

Comment: Web Application and LinqPad are accessing identical databases (number of rows, indexes)?

Comment: yes the exact same database

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `secondList` retrieval to call `ToList()` after the `where` condition is added. This avoids bringing down records to the client unnecessarily. In this case, you don't need `ToList()` at all, as you can just include the `where` as part of your linq query.

```
var lst = from n in numberGroups
          where n.RemainderLIB != null)
          select new {
             RemainderCHAPLIB = n.RemainderCHAPLIB,
             RemainderLIB = n.RemainderLIB,
             RemainderRUNUM = n.RemainderRUNUM,
             VAL = n.vals.FirstOrDefault(),
             ANT = n.vals.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
          };
```

Comment: ok there is some progress, with this query   var lst = from n in `numberGroups.
                Where(a => a.RemainderLIB != null)
                          select new
                          {
                              RemainderCHAPLIB = n.RemainderCHAPLIB,
                              RemainderLIB = n.RemainderLIB,
                              RemainderRUNUM = n.RemainderRUNUM,
                              VAL = n.vals.FirstOrDefault()
                          };`

Comment: Add ` signs before and after (click help next to comment box for more info)

Comment: anyway i ot about 4/5 seconds, still slow ! but if i add the last field ANT = n.vals.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault() i get an exception

Comment: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.